# what are programming languages i need to learn to create an windows phone app?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I am no programmer. I don't know any programming language .. But just started to learn java straight.. Without knowing any other language.. But I want to create an app for android and windows but I know to create an app for android I need to,know android java JavaScript CSS SQL to create an app . Like that what are the languages I need to know to create an whole windows phone app.. Which is main for a simple app

Answer (score 2):

I mean you can create a Windows app a bunch of different ways, but if you want to make it natively, you'll at least have to use C#/XAML.